# What is the largest a player character can get using only official material and UA?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, character-creation, creature-size

I was presented a concept for a one shot session from one of my players. He comes up with some strange ideas, and I'd like to see if this one would be viable:

The scenario goes that the Tarrasque has a prophesied date of awakening, so an elite order was created for the sole purpose of combating the creature to put it back in the ground. Using a combination of training courses over the course of many years (multiclassing into very specific classes), each of the group can become as large, if not larger than the Tarrasque and, for the lack of a better term, wrestle it to death.

My question is: Is there actually a combination of class features and spells that can push a character to get larger than a Tarrasque? And if it is, what kind of bonuses should such a character get upon reaching that size?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [How large is it possible for a PC to get?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148031)

Comment: Your title question is asking about how large can a PC possibly get, but your body is asking about whether such a size increase would be effective in fighting a Tarrasque. I think the Tarrasque question would be an interesting question that isn't a duplicate of what Rubiksmoose linked.

Comment: Why do you think there's a monster in the MM that you're not meant to fight? But please also see DucksGoMooful comment about if you're asking how large can you get vs how effective will size be.

Comment: Do you mean larger in creature size category or larger in actual dimensions?

Comment: Heavily related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128828/is-it-possible-for-a-pc-to-become-huge-or-larger-in-order-to-try-and-grapple-a

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate, but outside of the comment I asked above have you reviewed the grappling rules? What do you mean by "wrestle it to death?"

Comment: Since the duplicate question already seems to clearly answer what size you can get to, do you think you might just want to reference that and instead ask: "What kind of bonuses does a gargantuan PC get that would help them to fight a tarrasque?" Is that what you are trying to ask here? If you go this direction, you may want to say what you mean by "wrestle it to death" as well.

Comment: Worth noting that you also have enough reputation  to join and post in [RPG Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) where we can help you out with this question if you wanted.

Comment: "And if it is, what kind of bonuses should such a character get upon reaching that size?" - I think this should be another question, since I don't think this being tacked on the end of this question is enough to justify reopening this as not a dupe when it is besides this extra question...

Comment: @NathanS Reconfiguring the question to get it reopened I think would be perfectly fine. We just have to hear back from PyroTornado as to what their real question is. Hopefully they'll reengage :)